# Check if exists or not in the same line PHP

Tags: php

How can i check if exists or not in the same line something like that but it dosen't work :

```
<td><?= isset([$a['type1']]) ? [$a['type1']] : "0"; ?></td>
```

This's my code :

```
<td align="center" valign="top" class="textContent">                                                        
   <h2 style="text-align:center;font-weight:normal;font-  family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:23px;margin-bottom:10px;color:#72C8F3;line-height:135%;">Error1 : '.($a["type1"]).' <br/>Error2 : '.($a["type2"]).'<br/>Error3 : '.($a["type3"]).'</h3>
</td>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are there any errors?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplishw ith `[$a...]`? That's a new array containing a single element.

Comment: I want to check a values of : type1,type2 and type3 if it it exists if not return 0 in the same line.

Comment: so you want to check type2 exists too, or just echo the value if type one exists?

Comment: it not exists return 0. for type1,type 2 and type 3 too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator as followed. Note you don't need to wrap the array in '[]'

```
<?php echo (isset($a['type1']) ? $a['type1'] : 0); ?>
```

If you want to check all are set you could use;

```
<?php echo ( isset($a['type1']) && isset($a['type2']) && isset($a['type3'] ) ?  $a['type1'] : 0 ); ?>
```

To simplify further as suggested by Magnus Eriksson:

```
<?php echo ( isset($a['type1'], $a['type2'], $a['type3']) ?  $a['type1'] : 0 ); ?>
```

If you wish to check for just one use the or/double pipe `||` expression

```
<?php echo ( isset($a['type1']) || isset($a['type2']) || isset($a['type3'] ) ?  $a['type1'] : 0 ); ?>
```

Comment: I think it should return `$a['type1']`, not `$a['type2']`, since it is the first you're checking if it is set.

Comment: that would make sense. However type2 was the OP original question. Maybe he wants to check type two as well?

Comment: @atoms : yeah it's type1 :<?php echo (isset($a['type1']) ? $a['type1'] : 0); ?>. I didn't pay attention

Comment: @zouzou thanks, I have updated my answer. If its resolved your issue please mark as correct

Comment: You're second example could be even simpler by passing all variables in the same isset: `isset($a['type1'], $a['type2'], $a['type3'])`. That's the same thing as having three `isset()` in a row.

Comment: derrr, thank you will update answer, unless you want to post it?

Comment: I check just type2 and the value is equal to 12 but it return nothing.

Comment: then you need to do an or between each one, will update my answer

Comment: then I suggest you examine the values using var_dump($a['type1']) etc, confirm that they are as expected.

Comment: N.B type2 might have a value, however type1 might not. As thats what is returned if type2 is set

Answer (score 4):

PHP 7 introduces the so called null coalescing operator which simplifies the statements to:

```
$var = $var ?? "default";
```

So, your code would become

```
<td> <?php echo $a['type1'] ?? "0"; ?> </td>
```